# Finding last index of a string in Oracle

Tags: oracle, string

I need to find the last index of a string (e.g. `-`) within another string (e.g. `JD-EQ-0001` in Oracle's SQL (*version 8i*).  Is there a way to do this with `INSTR()` or another function?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Use -1 as the start position:

```
INSTR('JD-EQ-0001', '-', -1)
```