# IndexOf Feature in Pl/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, indexof

I'd like to look up the location of a specific character in a varchar variable.

Comment: See this post **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856817/finding-last-index-of-a-string-in-oracle)**  there is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [instr](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)