# How to get file extension of file as a result of sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, dao

I have a table named `datas` and I'm executing a query like this:

```
SELECT linkurl AS DOWNLOADURL,
       lastrevlevel AS VERSION,
       code AS DESCRIPTION,
       created AS RELEASEDATE,
       name AS TYPE
FROM datas
WHERE id IN (SELECT child_id
          FROM   datas _datas
          WHERE  parent_id = (SELECT Max(id)
                              FROM   datas
                              WHERE  code = 'AN4307SW'))
```

It returns results like this:

```
DOWNLOADURL               VERSION DESCRIPTION RELEASEDATE    TYPE
/artifacts/download.txt   2.0     images       25/6/12      download.txt
```

In the `Type` column I am geting name of the file. I need to get the file extension of the file name in the `Type` column. How can I achieve this?

Examples:

```
TYPE
.txt
.pdf
.xls
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if I had a file named `Test.Document.doc` ? What about if no extension was specified?

Comment: @bridge i want only extension of file name

Comment: @anto So the substring after the last dot - in my example `doc`. Is it possible that there could be a file without an extension (not containing a dot at all?)

Comment: @bridge: yes there is a chance of not getting dot, then how should i proceed

Comment: @anto In that case, the accepted answer which uses `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return the whole name of the file if there is no dot. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @Bridge: but i am having certain other fields which would definitely have extension at last.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). Like this:

```
select linkurl as DOWNLOADURL,lastrevlevel as VERSION,
code  as DESCRIPTION,created as RELEASEDATE,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',-1) as TYPE
from datas where id in
(select child_id from datas _datas 
where parent_id=( select max(id) from datas 
where code = 'AN4307SW'))
```

**EDIT**

If you see the docs on this function I think this will apply well to you requirements.

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

This will also handle a case like this:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('Test.Document.doc','.',-1);
```

**EDIT2**

If you are using oracle. Please tag the question in the correct matter next time. There is no `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in oracle. But what I can see you can do this quite easy:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Test.Document.doc', INSTR('Test.Document.doc', '.',-1)) 
FROM dual;
```

Full query like this:

```
select linkurl as DOWNLOADURL,lastrevlevel as VERSION,
    code  as DESCRIPTION,created as RELEASEDATE,
    SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, '.',-1))  as TYPE
    from datas where id in
    (select child_id from datas _datas 
    where parent_id=( select max(id) from datas 
    where code = 'AN4307SW'))
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856817/finding-last-index-of-a-string-in-oracle)

Comment: thnks but when i execute this query its showing invalid identifier SUBSTRING_INDEX .. i am using oracle

Comment: @anto in tags You've mention mysql.

Comment: @arion: thanks it works well,if i need .txt,.pdf,.xls what should i do?

Comment: @anto : I update the answer for that. You need to remove the +1. Have a look

Comment: this is super helpful, thanks from 10 years in the future! just want to point out that SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',-1) yields the file extension _without_ a dot, whereas OP wanted it _with_ a dot.

Answer (score 2):

```
select linkurl as DOWNLOADURL,lastrevlevel as VERSION,
code  as DESCRIPTION,created as RELEASEDATE,reverse(substring(reverse(name), 1,charindex('.', reverse(name))-1)) as TYPE
from datas where id in
(select child_id from datas _datas 
where parent_id=( select max(id) from datas 
where code = 'AN4307SW'))
```

Comment: ...just tried this solution works well, also covers scenarios where a file name might look like this 'some.thing.txt'

Answer (score 1):

think you'll need something like this

```
SELECT REPLACE(name,SUBSTRING(name ,0, CHARINDEX('.', name )),'')
```

Comment: select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(name),1,LOCATE('.',REVERSE(name),1)))

Comment: I want to post it as another ans but its get posted as comment here wrongly. but how do i delete this comment ? there is no option to delete

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(file_name,(LENGTH(file_name)-LOCATE('.',REVERSE(file_name)))+2)
FROM <table name> WHERE file_id=<file_id>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(name),1,LOCATE('.',REVERSE(name),1‌​)));
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(FILE_NAME,"." ,-1) from TABLE_NAME
```