# Find the last position of an element in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tring to find the last position of an element in a column in sql (oracle). If I have on a column the value `20-7-1-2-2` I need the position of the last `-` which is `9`. Any ideas how I could find it?

Comment: A Google search turned up this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/856832/50552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
select INSTR(columnname, '-', -1) from tablename
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86512/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select instr('20-7-1-2-2', '-', -1, 1) from dual
-------------------------------------^
```

-1 means search from end of string

See the [Oracle Instr reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm).