# Split column which have two or three word by space in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I have a legacy column in my table which stores name and surname values together. 
For Example:  `Mike Huge Muyra` or `John Kutgira`.

I need to split column by whitespace.

Result must be like that (**Last word is surname, others are name**)

```
Name : Mike Huge,  Surname : Muyra
Name : John,       Surname : Kutgira
```

I have been researching for two hours. (**REGEXP_SUBSTR** is looking cool) But I can not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this.  However, because the rule involves the *last* space perhaps regular string operations are fine:

```
select trim(substr(legacy, 1 - instr(reverse(legacy), ' '))) as surname,
       trim(substr(legacy, 1, length(legacy) - instr(reverse(legacy), ' '))) as restname
```

You might want to wrap these in `case legacy like '% %'` just to be sure they have a space.

Comment: Works perfect. Just add TRIM() for before and after whitespaces. Everythink is OK. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try finding out the last index of space (' ') character and then using substring (twice I guess for first and last part) to get what you want.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856817/finding-last-index-of-a-string-in-oracle) for the last index of part.

Comment: PS : There is http://dba.stackexchange.com/ too, you may find some help there as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select trim(substr(:p_str, 1, instr(:p_str, ' ', -1)-1)) first_name,
       trim(substr(:p_str, instr(:p_str, ' ', -1)+1)) surname 
  from dual;
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.