# how to split the value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have worked with MySQL and new to oracle. In MySQL we have a function SUBSTRING_INDEX(), I want to replace it in oracle, Any help plz

```
 SQL>select SUBSTRING_INDEX('JD;EQ;0001', ';', -1) from dual;
```

Result:

0001

I want a same result in oracle. Is there any function in oracle that return the same result in oracle?

I have tried but no expected result.

```
  SELECT substr('CLUBORACLE',3,2) RES FROM dual;
```

Comment: I think you'll find this to be a useful resource: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('JD;EQ;0001', INSTR('JD;EQ;0001', ';', -1) + 1) FROM dual
```

In the query above, `INSTR('JD;EQ;0001', ';', -1)` would return `6`, which is the position of the *last* semicolon in the expression.  You want to take the substring from the position *after* the last semicolon until the end of the string.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856817/finding-last-index-of-a-string-in-oracle) for a good SO question about Oracle's `INSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('JD;EQ;0001', '[^;]+', 1, your_occurance_number) FROM dual;` but SUBSTR+INSTR should be faster.